# Is there a self tuning thread pool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I do not always know the optimal thread pool size because it depends on the number of cores and on the ratio of cpu and io work that my threads do. No doubt I can profile and pick an optimal size. 
Also I can write my own smart pool that over time will adjust to be optimal. But before I do it, is there code or library that does it?

Tnx

Comment: Well, all default thread pools which you do not size yourself have pretty sane defaults; an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` for instance.

Comment: Requests for third party resources are off-topic; but you could use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` to get the number of cores.

Comment: @fge Typically `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` is not a good solution if you are submitting potentially many tasks. For each task submitted in which there aren't threads available it will create a new one which can literally bring a system down if not used correctly.

Comment: Amdahl's law, and Runtime available processors.

Comment: Amdahl's Law + cores is clear. The question is whether there is code that will calculate its optimal size by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue similar to this.

I had an arbitrary amount of heavily I/O bound tasks (Runnables, or Callables) which I needed to run in a fixed time slice. This happens over and over on a fixed interval. As an example let's say I every 3000ms I needed to make sure I could execute 143 tasks that were heavily bound by network I/O.

I ended up with [this as a solution](https://github.com/egineering-llc/collectd-fast-jmx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/e_gineering/collectd/SelfTuningCollectionExecutor.java), and it seems to work pretty well. Basically I track a some internal metrics for pool sizes and task success / fail rates and latency. Within a handful of iterations there's enough information to project responsible sizes for how big the pool ought to be, and then refine the pool size from there to slowly approach a minimum pool size that accomplishes the execution goal within the proper timeframe.

I never bothered to generalize it outside of my specific use-case, but I'm pretty sure there's opportunity there to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't the [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) solve your problem?

From the javadoc:

> Creates a ForkJoinPool with parallelism equal to Runtime.availableProcessors()

Comment: (no idea who downvoted, that was not me) A `ForkJoinPool` is pretty specialized; it is not a generalized `ThreadPoolExecutor` like what is provided by `Executors.*`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought since `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` created a `ForkJoinPool` that it might be a good match

Comment: ForkJoinPool is not good for my case. Imagine I have code that spends 75% of time in cpu and 25% in io. This means that if I have 8 cores, I can have 12 threads in the pool and this way all cores will be used 100%. I can profile and come up with this number manually but ideally a pool would measure the performance of its threads and over time adjust to the optimal number of threads.